# Recursively select children node using XPath recursively?

Tags: c#, xpath

Given the following XML:

```
<Checks>
   <IsSomethingCheck Param="1"/>
   <IsSomeoneCheck Param2="2"/>
   <Checks Operator="Or">
       <IsAnythingCheck Param3="3"/>
   </Checks>
</Checks>
```

How would I traverse the children of `Checks` element recursively?

The code below works for the outermost children but stops processing the inner most children (Part of the inner `Checks` element)

```
protected override void InitializePlugin(XmlElement xmlElement)
{
    Enum.TryParse(xmlElement.GetAttribute("Operator"), out _operator);

    XPathNodeIterator nav = xmlElement.CreateNavigator().Select("Checks/*");

    foreach (XPathNavigator checkNode in nav)
    {
        if (_checksLookup.ContainsKey(checkNode.Name))
        {
            Type checkType = _checksLookup[checkNode.Name];
            Check check = Activator.CreateInstance(checkType) as Check;
            check.Initialize(checkNode.OuterXml);
            Checks.Add(check);
        }
    }    
}
```

PS: The XmlElement of this method expects that it will receive the entire `Checks` section of the XML.

Answer (score 2):

Found it! XPath expression should be `/CheckManager/*` not `CheckManager/*`.